# How use my data with Charts.js in my case?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, chart.js

I use Charts.js in my Angular project (not AngularJS) and i want to use data from my database to make a graphic with woman / man, but i didn't know how create a loop and count number of woman or number of men :

First, for the Chart, my html code :

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="700" height="400"></canvas>
```

typescript :

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
          labels: ["Femme", "Homme"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [2,2],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        display:true
      }
    });
  }
```

and the code to get my data :

javascript :

```
app.get("/api/getUser",function(req,res){
    model.find({},function(err,data){
              if(err){
                  res.send(err);
              }
              else{
                  res.send(data);
                  }
          });
  })
```

typescript :

```
GetUser(){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/getUser/')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  }
```

and the second typescript :

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.newService.GetUser().subscribe(data =>  this.Repdata = data)
  }
```

for finish, this is the collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b9551a60e89ad15a8ff77fb"),
    "name" : "XXX",
    "prenom" : "KEVIN",
    "datenaissance" : "17/11/2011",
    "mail" : "KEVIN@laposte.fr",
    "tel" : "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "sexe" : "Homme",
    "adresse" : "XXXXXXXX",
    "note" : [ 
        {
            "matiere" : "Français",
            "note" : "10/20",
            "date" : "01/09/2018"
        }, 
        {
            "matiere" : "Anglais",
            "note" : "07/20",
            "date" : "26/09/2018"
        }, 
        {
            "matiere" : "EPS",
            "note" : "15/20",
            "date" : "29/09/2018"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to count the number of sexe:Homme and sexe:Femme to use this for create my graphic but i didn't know how

thank you very much

If I do this my charts can't find the countHomme and countFemme :

javascript :

```
 app.get("/api/getUser",function(req,res){
    model.find({},function(err,data){
              if(err){
                  res.send(err);
              }
              else{
                  res.send(data);
                  var countHomme = model.where({ 'sexe': 'Homme' }).count();
                  res.send(countHomme);
                  var countFemme = model.where({ 'sexe': 'Femme' }).count();
                  res.send(countFemme);
                  }
          });
  })
```

typescript :

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
    let myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
      type: 'pie',
      data: {
          labels: ["Femme", "Homme"],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [countFemme,countHomme],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
      },
      options: {
        responsive: false,
        display:true
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO, its better to ask the data about male and female sex from the backend through an API.
You can try to count the fields using mongoose ORM via [Model.count()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count) method and it can send back a JSON object with total counts as per your need and you can feed it directly to chart.js

Comment: I didn't see how can i do this

Comment: Lets say the name of your model is User, than you can do something like this 
`user.where({ 'sexe': 'Homme' }).count()`
Here have a look at the [mongoose docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count)

Comment: I try and re-try but i didn't find the solution, i add a new "proposition" but i didn't know how send data from my file.js to my app.component.ts